# React Inline Style - How to style automatic generated tags?

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles, slick.js

I'm using Slick Carousel with React but i need modify some styles of some divs which are automatically created by Slick.

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';

export default class Slider extends React.Component {
    render: function () {
        var settings = {
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
        };

        return (
            <Slider {...settings}>
                <div><h3>1</h3></div>
                <div><h3>2</h3></div>
                <div><h3>3</h3></div>
                <div><h3>4</h3></div>
                <div><h3>5</h3></div>
                <div><h3>6</h3></div>
            </Slider>
        );
    }
});
```

Because i set **dots = true**, so the **dots** will be displayed below my slider. But i need to change its style. With inline style, how can i do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you post a sample of your code?

Comment: Of course, i've updated my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit - as noted later by [Hung Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6618786/hung-nguyen) slick has a [dotsClass](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in their settings API so that might be simpler. Thanks Hung!*

- When something like that is not available though, this still works for grabbing unknown elements after render:

Using the lifecycle event [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) allows you to look for the elements after render().  You can use [ReactDOM.findDOMNode()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode) to get the real DOM elements (not the React virtual DOM).  Then just identify the elements you need and change their style.

[Demo using a Fork of react-slick](https://jsfiddle.net/shawn1/8u2d15f2/)

```
var ReactSlickDemo = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    //find the unknown slider elements here
    var elements = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).children[0];
    //modifying styles
    elements.style.border = "5px solid red";
  },

  render: function() {
    var settings = {
      dots: true
    }
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Slider {...settings} >
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactSlickDemo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: That's what i need. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with the Slick carousel, but in general the way to do inline styles in react is the following:

1.- create a style object, with keys that are the CSS style names, but camel cased. So for instance, `font-size` becomes `fontSize`, `border-with` becomes `borderWidth`, etc.

2.- Assign that object to the `style` prop of your JSX element.

You could also assign the styles object directly to the prop, as a literal

An example from the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html):

```
var divStyle = {
  color: 'white',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
  WebkitTransition: 'all', // note the capital 'W' here
  msTransition: 'all' // 'ms' is the only lowercase vendor prefix
};

ReactDOM.render(<div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
```

There are also more complete solutions for inline styles, like [Radium](http://stack.formidable.com/radium/), if you decide to go full inline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I know Radium but in this case, not only Slick but with all carousel library, the **dots** are created automatically and their divs are not in my code. So i don't know how to assign a style to these divs.

Comment: documentation for Slick carousel talks about a dotClass string you can pass to style the dots. Does it HAVE to be inline?

`dotsClass  string  Class applied to the dots if they are enabled  Yes`

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best way is to use *dotsClass* to re-style the style of dots by yourself

```
var ReactSlickDemo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var settings = {
        dots: true,
      dotsClass: 'custom-dots'
    }
        return (
        <div className='container'>
        <Slider {...settings} >
            <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactSlickDemo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[Full demo with CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/t8yfjzmm/)

This is another way. Only use this if you don't need to change style of active dot

```
var ReactSlickDemo = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var $stickContainer = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).find('.stickContainer');
    // Need to defer because there is no dots at this moment
    // Dots are rendered after slide content rendered for calculating number of slide
    // https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/src/inner-slider.jsx#L101
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $dots = $stickContainer.find('li');
      $dots.css('background-color', 'red');
        }, 0);
  },

  render: function() {
    var settings = {
        dots: true,
      className: 'stickContainer'
    }
        return (
        <div className='container'>
        <Slider {...settings} >
            <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
          <div><img src='http://placekitten.com/g/400/200' /></div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactSlickDemo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zr2haah8/)

Answer (score 0):

simply use css with :global

```
:global(.slick-active){
        background-color:#71afe5
    }
```

Works for me